# How to make a closure typed 'extern "C" fn'

Tags: rust

This is short example about this question.

```
#[fixed_stack_segment]
fn test(func: extern "C" fn() -> ~str) -> ~str {
    func()
}
extern "C" fn func1() -> ~str {
    ~"hello"
}

fn main() {
    let func2 = || -> ~str { ~"world" };
    println(test(func1));
    println(test(func2));
}
```

Then, rustc stops with error.

```
st.rs:13:17: 13:22 error: mismatched types: expected `extern "C" fn() -> ~str` but found `&fn<no-bounds>() -> ~str` (expected extern fn but found fn)
st.rs:13     println(test(func2));
```

I cannot find a way to make the lambda be an extern fn.

What should I do?

Comment: I don't think you can, because closures imply captured environment, and extern functions do not have any environment. I'm not sure though, let's wait for more authoritative answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The closure syntax is always either `&fn` or `~fn`, and to make an `extern "ABI" fn` (for any value of `ABI`, including `Rust`), one needs to use a full function declaration.

```
#[fixed_stack_segment]
fn test(func: extern "C" fn() -> ~str) -> ~str {
    func()
}
extern "C" fn func1() -> ~str {
    ~"hello"
}

fn main() {
    extern "C" fn func2() -> ~str { ~"world" } 

    println(test(func1));
    println(test(func2));
}
```

There is some talk of allowing lambdas to create non-closures too, with the ABI inferred like anything else in a type signature, but this isn't implemented yet.

---

However, as Vladimir Matveev says, there is a fundamental difference between closures and normal functions, which means that one will never be able to use all the features of closures when passed as an `extern fn`. The difference is closures can capture (references to) variables, i.e.

```
let n = 1;
let f = || { n + 1 };
```

This means a closure is effectively represented by

```
struct AndFn { // &fn
    env: &Environment,
    func: extern "Rust" fn()
}

struct TwiddleFn { // ~fn
    env: ~Environment,
    func: extern "Rust" fn()
}
```

where `Environment` is a struct that contains all the capture variables for that closure (it differs for each `&fn`, since each one captures different things); the `func` is a function pointer to the code of the closure, which is what gets executed when the closure is called; if a closure captures any variables, the `func` will require the `env` to exist. Thus, the lambda syntax will only be able to create plain `extern fn`s when it captures no variables.

Comment: Hmm..., I tried to use [rust-mozjs](https://github.com/mozilla-servo/rust-mozjs) and want to wrap JSFuntionSpec(It requires 'extern "C" fn').

Thank you! I'm going to find other way.